# Group By Error in Nested Function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a data table Employees. I want to show the employees who earn more than the average salary of all employees in the employees table. The code I have written so far is:

```
select employee_id, last_name, salary
from employees
group by employee_id
having salary > (select avg(sum(salary))
                 from employees);
```

However, when I run this, a "nested function without group by" error occurred. How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't you just want the avg?  no need for sum?  isn't avg the sum of all employee salaries divided by the count?  so why sum?  the math doesn't make sense and the compiler is asking you to better define what you're after. maybe you mean: `having salary > (select avg(salary)
                 from employees);`  and no need for the outer group by if you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` unnecessary.  The outer group by is on no aggregation.  Group by is only needed when an aggregate function is being used.  Since no aggregate function, no group by!

Double aggregation `(avg(sum(salary))` in subquery not needed  Avg, in and of itself, will return an average.  Not sure what the sum was attempting to do. if you Avg the sum you'll end up with the sum. (Say I have 1,2,3,4,5:  the sum is 15  the avg of the sum is 15.  However, the avg is 3.)

And with no `GROUP BY`,  `HAVING` becomes a `WHERE`.

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary
FROM  employees
WHERE salary > (SELECT avg(salary)
                 FROM employees);
```

Comment: Thanks xQbert! What a silly mistake I made; forgot that just Avg is enough.

Comment: We all need a 2nd set of eyes sometimes.  ( I usually need 2 1/2 more brains too; 1 & 1/2 to make up for the mistakes i make)